# How can I make a Bootstrap 3 Collapse work with SimpleForm checkbox in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I am trying to use the Bootstrap Collapse to open a section only if the box here is checked.  I am using [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).  I can get the toggle to work fine in the page with a normal link, but I can't get SimpleForm to put the data-toggle bit in.

**I need this in input:**

```
 data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseOne"

<%= f.input :boolean_question, inline_label: 'Check if true'%>
```

[image]

**Any ideas on how to make this happen?**  I have tried input_html:  and wrapper_html:

**UPDATE: for now this is my solution without simple_form:**

```
<%= form_for(@model) do |f| %>

<%= f.check_box :boolean_question, data: {'toggle' =>  "collapse", 'target' =>  "#collapse_section"} %>

<div id="collapse_section" class="collapse">
  Data that was hidden
</div>
```

Comment: What about using straight JQuery? `$(':checkbox').on('click') -> $('#collapsable').css('display: block/none;')`

Comment: @Chloe Thanks -I tried that, but could not get it working.  I updated the above to work without simple_form but I would still love to see a solution that would work with simple_form.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this:

```
<%= f.input :boolean_question, label: false, inline_label: 'Check if Yes',
input_html: { data: {'toggle' =>  "collapse", 'target' =>  "#collapse_section"} } %>
```

Plus:

```
   <div id="collapse_section" class="collapse">
       <p>hidden stuff that will be revealed.</p>
   </div>
```